# How to measure a shape angle

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

Working with photoshop cs4 and given the image below, I need to measure the angle marked by the red line and turn the other figure. The objective is to have 5 similar figures in perfect circle, this means at the exact same distance each other. The final result should look like a round.

[image]

What would be the most efficient, correct method of doing this?

Comment: Have you a possiblity to visit in Illustrator? There are easy methods to place shapes along curves and form exactly aligned groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **Ruler Tool** and pen the **Measurement Log ** (`Window > Measurement Log`).

Click-drag with the Ruler Tool along the path to measure. Then click the <kbd>Record Measurement</kbd> button on the Log Panel. All the way on the right side, the Angle at which you dragged will be logged.
[image]

This is, after all, just a click-drag. So, it is far from being absolutely precise because it relies on the user to drag correctly.

Comment: so rotating by that value the other image should line up?

Comment: Yes if you are accurate when you drag to create the measurement. Generally you have to zoom in and try a couple times.